# Need to Optimise the following MySQL query

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I've tried this query successfully with a limit. The following query runs endless without limit:

> ```
> SELECT o.product_sku
> FROM   order_table o
> WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
>            FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT u.type_id,
>                                    u.charge_type,
>                                    u.billed_weight
>                    FROM   ups_table u
>                    WHERE  charge_type = 'order_shipping_table'
>                           AND NOT billed_weight = '0'
>                    ) dtm
>            WHERE  o.order_id = dtm.type_id)
> GROUP  BY product_sku
> HAVING Count(product_sku) > 1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need these subqueries with DISTINCT and so on:

```
SELECT o.product_sku
FROM   order_table o
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   ups_table u
                   WHERE  charge_type = 'order_shipping_table'
                          AND NOT billed_weight = '0'
                          AND type_id=o.order_id
               )
GROUP  BY product_sku
HAVING Count(product_sku) > 1
```

I don't know your table structure (what do you want to count in the HAVING?) but you can try to change EXISTS to JOIN:

```
SELECT o.product_sku
FROM   order_table o
JOIN ups_table u on (u.type_id=o.order_id)
                    AND (u.charge_type = 'order_shipping_table')
                    AND NOT (billed_weight = '0')
GROUP  BY product_sku
HAVING Count(DISTINCT o.order_id) > 1
```

And you need indexes on `o.order_id, o.product_sku, u.type_id,u.charge_type, u.billed_weight`